# Plurality for the clause modifying the subject in plural form?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following sentence(s) is(are) grammatically correct? If more than one of them is, do these have different meanings? And why?

1. The copy process terminates unexpectedly if there **is a web page** with non-ASCII **filename**.
2. The copy process terminates unexpectedly if there **is a web page** with **a** non-ASCII **filename**.
3. The copy process terminates unexpectedly if there **are web pages** with non-ASCII **filename**.
4. The copy process terminates unexpectedly if there **are web pages** with **a** non-ASCII **filename**.
5. The copy process terminates unexpectedly if there **are web pages** with non-ASCII **filenames**.

I want to express that the copy process fails upon encountering **one or more** bad page(s). I am not sure whether the subject (page) should be singular or plural.

Additionally, **all the "bad page" mentioned above must fullfill the condition "the page has exactly one non-ASCII filename"** (we assume that a page could only have one filename). I am not sure whether the "with" clause should be plural (match the "page", if used as plural previously) or singular (match the "filename", or "page" if used as singular previously).

If, as a possible sense, that a web page could have multiple filenames (if embeded images, fonts, etc. are counted as part of the web page), which of the above sentence is suitable for expressing it in this case?

Comment: Either #3 or #5 but not both.

Comment: @Mitch Would that you were as assiduous at spotting other duplicates.

Comment: I'd go with #2 - it translates roughly to *stop if there exists at least one web page containing a non-ASCII filename*. However, #5 also works idiomatically.

Answer (score 1):

Either #2 or {#3 and #5} would be correct, depending on how the system actually faults. Does the copy process explode upon encountering **one** nonconforming web page (answer #2)? Or only when it has encountered **multiple** naughty ones (answers #3 and #5)?

Comment: Disclaimer: This answer is **not** supported by references or documentation of any kind.

Comment: Edited the original question and added some explanation.